# Location and config for local Cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

I have a standard Cordova project that looks like this:

```
build.json
config.xml
hooks/
my-custom-plugin/
  src/
  www/
  package.json
  plugin.xml
package-lock.json
package.json
res/
www/
```

I wrote a custom plugin, which I keep in a subdirectory of the project. I added it to my Cordova project like this:

```
cordova plugin add my-custom-plugin
```

It added the following to `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="my-custom-plugin" spec="my-custom-plugin" />
```

and to package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-custom-plugin": "file:my-custom-plugin"
```

I prefer not to commit `node_modules/`, `plugins/`, or `platforms/` to SCM; I want to let Cordova recreate those as part of my build process.

But when I check out the above project and run `cordova prepare --verbose`, it gives me an error:

```
Failed to restore plugin "my-custom-plugin" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin my-custom-plugin@file:my-custom-plugin via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "my-custom-plugin" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

(This last message isn't right; as you can see above, it does contain a valid package.json file.)

The detailed error log has:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'my-custom-plugin@file:my-custom-plugin' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose npm-session 2b51ee3ccee75e63
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for my-custom-plugin@file:my-custom-plugin Could not install from "my-custom-plugin" as it does not contain a package.json file.
8 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my-project/node_modules/my-custom-plugin/package.json'
9 verbose cwd /my-project/node_modules
10 verbose Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64
11 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "my-custom-plugin@file:my-custom-plugin"
12 verbose node v8.9.4
13 verbose npm  v5.6.0
14 error code ENOLOCAL
15 error Could not install from "my-custom-plugin" as it does not contain a package.json file.
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If I try running `npm install` first, that command works, but the `cordova prepare` command still fails with the same error.

What's the correct way to do this?

I'm using cordova-cli 8.0.0, with node 8.9.4, on both MacOS and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, it's already reported
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13801

Comment: Thanks -- I'll follow up there.